# Import Math Module - Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am running some basic python functions. When I try to the import math module it doesn't seem to work properly. This is the code I received.

```
   In [5]: import math    

   In [6]: 2^3
   ...: (2)^3
   ...: 2^(3)
   ...: 2**3
   ...: improt math
  File "<ipython-input-6-92c86fb66a5e>", line 5
improt math
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In [7]2**3
Out [7]: 8

In [8]: import math
...: math.sqrt (81)
...: 
...: math
...: math .sqrt(81)
...: sqrt(81)
...: 2**3
```

I haven't configured the program or done anything beside play around with basic functions. But it isn't importing the math module. Any idea why?

Comment: `improt` is not the same as `import`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo - `improt` on line 5

Answer (score 0):

You can also import as

```
from math import *
```

Then you can use any mathematical function without prefixing math. e.g.

```
sqrt(81)
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the first line which didn't have the typo.  Nonetheless the import math function is working properly suddenly. Don't know why it was buggin